# How can I view the names of the layers of a model in TensorFlow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I would like to get the names of the different layers in a model in TensorFlow Object Detection API like a mobilenetv2 for example. The reason I want this is to modify feature_map_layout in feature_extractor.py. Without the names of the layers, I am not able to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: May be this app helps you : https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron